# What's the behavior of db.find.sort()?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

For example this is our document schema, which has an **descending index** on **created_at** field.

```
var titles = {
  title: String,
  created_at:{
    type: Date,
    index: -1
  }
}
```

Here are 2 questions:

**1st:**
If we call `db.titles.find()` or `db.titles.findOne()` how result order will be?
I mean it will returns objects in desc or asc order?

**2nd:**
How about here?

```
db.titles.find().sort({created_at: -1})
```

How does MongoDB behave in the code above? **Sort the result on the fly** or it just use **index order** which we defined in the **schema**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1st: If we call db.titles.find() or db.titles.findOne() how result
>   order will be? I mean it will returns objects in desc or asc order?

It will return documents in [natural order](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-natural-order) - in order in which documents are stored on disk. If you want to sort documents by `created_at` you should explicitly specify it:

```
db.titles.find().sort({created_at: -1})
```

> How does MongoDB behave in the code above? Sort the result on the fly
>   or it just use index order which we defined in the schema?

Since you already have an index on `created_at` field, Mongo will use it. But if you'll add some query

```
db.titles.find({title: /Foo/}).sort({created_at: -1})
```

then Mongo will no longer be able to use your index to sort query results and will be forced to sort it on the fly.

You can find more aboun MongoDB indexes [in this blog post](http://blog.mongolab.com/2012/06/cardinal-ins/).

Comment: Spasibo!
Just curious to know if there is any way to use indexes in advanced queries?

Comment: I just added a link to a blog post about MongoDB indexes.